# Flutter: FCM Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

> E/flutter (26872): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)]
> Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
> E/flutter (26872): #0
> MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.registerBackgroundMessageHandler
> (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_messaging.dart:173:53)
> E/flutter (26872): #1
> FirebaseMessagingPlatform.onBackgroundMessage=
> (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_messaging.dart:108:16)

```
// Background Messaging Set Up
    Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
        RemoteMessage message) async {
      print('background message');
    }

    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    runApp(....)
```

I am getting an error for this code on Android system. Everything works except when the app is terminated.

***What works on Android:***

- Notification when Terminated, onBackground and onForeground
- Date only when onForeground

***What does not work on Android:***

- Data only when Terminated and onBackground

***What works on iOS:***

- Notification when Terminated, onBackground and onForeground
- Date only when onForeground

***What does not work on iOS:***

- Data only when Terminated,

I have no clue why I am getting that null value error on Android system and how can I fix this issue? Also, is it true that I can not receive the `Data only` push notification on iOS when the app is terminated?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I had the same error as like you, on the same line. I checked out [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#background-messages) and it says 2 things about background message handler.

1. It must not be an anonymous function.
2. It must be a top-level function (e.g. not a class method which requires initialization).

In my case it was not a top-level function, it was declared inside a class. When you move your handler out of any class or function, so that it is a top-level function and doesn't require any class or method initialisation then the error will be gone.

Comment: It was from my stupidity that `top-level` function -> put it on top of the class.

Comment: @chichi same stupidity here :)

Comment: @swifthing well, looks like not just us XD

Comment: dont forget to add @pragma('vm:entry-point') above a function: `@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _messageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {}` as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#apple_platforms_and_android)

Answer (score 24):

_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler function should be outside of the main function.

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}


Future<void> main() async {

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);


  runApp(
    ...
  );
}
```

Comment: Right. When I read about `top-level`, I assumed that I had to put it on top inside the class or function. I've realized it meant `OUTSIDE`.

Comment: Yes, put outside :)

Answer (score 6):

In my case, doing what docs said was not enough. So I realized that I should add `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` before everything in main function like this:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_handleMessage);
  runApp(const Homino());
}
```