# Is it possible to execute dart code, on receiving a FCM notification, without user interaction

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, sip, voip

In my app, I have added support for VOIP calls, and I have a requirement that if a notification is received in `terminated` state, then the `controller` that is responsible for registering the user at the SIP server, is triggered.

I have triggered my controller inside `onBackgroundMessage`

```
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(
          (message) => firebaseService.firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(message));
```

The `firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler` triggers the controller, but as per my testing, the this is not behaving as expected.

Comment: This is the solution to the problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67704651/10285344